# Dealing with Mysql Replication and Functions

Tags: mysql, replication, consistency

In MySQL replication Master-Slave, is there anyway to deal with the functions:

- LOAD_FILE()
- UUID(), UUID_SHORT()
- USER()
- FOUND_ROWS()
- SYSDATE()
- GET_LOCK()
- IS_FREE_LOCK()
- IS_USED_LOCK()
- MASTER_POS_WAIT()
- RAND()
- RELEASE_LOCK()
- SLEEP()
- VERSION()

We have Replication and I am kind of worry for the consistency of the data, I.E in my localhost.

**MASTER**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `t1` (   `number_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL );
mysql> insert into t1 values (uuid_short());
mysql> select * from t1;
+-------------------+
| number_id         |
+-------------------+
| 95769054064672779 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Slave**

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+--------------------+
| number_id          |
+--------------------+
| 167826651055390725 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Master**

```
mysql> update t1 set number_id=0 where number_id='95769054064672779';
mysql> select * from t1;
+-----------+
| number_id |
+-----------+
| 0         |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Slave**

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+--------------------+
| number_id          |
+--------------------+
| 167826651055390725 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there anyway to deal with it? I am not a programmer, should the programmers knows that it's replication database so he can start using variables with Mysql Functions to keep the consistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is completely unacceptable, and developers should not be expected to work around it.

You've suppressed it in your answer, and I don't know if you didn't notice it, or didn't consider it significant, or something is broken in your setup.  Here's what you should have seen:

```
mysql> insert into t1 values (uuid_short());
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.11 sec)
```

Notice the 1 warning.

```
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1592 | Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it uses a system function that may return a different value on the slave. |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

So your simple fix is "don't use statement format."

Clean up those discrepant tables, and then...

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL BINLOG_FORMAT = MIXED;
```

Then, prepare yourself for what follows... because `MIXED` mode is more correct and deterministic than `STATEMENT` mode, it's also more likely to detect cases where your servers are *already* inconsistent, and replication will stop.  Don't be confused that `MIXED` mode has broken it... `MIXED` mode will just tend to uncover problems you already have.

The same thing goes for `ROW` format, which is even more aggressive at maintaining identical data, and is my preferred `BINLOG_FORMAT` for that reason, among others.

You also need to set this in your `my.cnf` file so that the setting persists if the server is restarted.

But once you aren't using `STATEMENT` mode any more, this issue should completely disappear.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did the test and it worked nice, do you have any idea what is the maximum number of master in a multi master replication?

Comment: @jcho360 there's not really a meaningful limit.  You'd have to stay below 255 masters to avoid collisions in `UUID_SHORT()` and below 65,535 masters to avoid problems with `auto_increment_offset` and `_increment` but those are all unreasonably large numbers of master servers.  Avoiding consistency issues becomes almost exponentially complex as master server count rises. If you need more than 2, look at Galera in MariaDB or Percona server, both MySQL compatible, for synchronous replication.

Comment: On the other hand, the number of read-only slaves you can deploy is virtually unlimited, since slaves can cascade from other slaves, as well as from the master.